# Websocket: Is it necessary to send ping messages by hand? (e.g between fiber websocket server & js client in browser)

Tags: javascript, go, websocket, go-fiber

I've wrtten a websocket server in `fiber`'s [websocket](https://github.com/gofiber/websocket), and the client is [js websocket](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSocket) in browser.

Some **questions** regarding `ping`/`pong`:

1. Is there any default ping/pong msg between the websocket server & client?
   If yes, then why I can't see it in chrome's devtools.
2. If there isn't any defult ping/pong msg, should I add ping/pong between server & client myself?
3. If it's a good practice to add ping/pong msg myself, then:
4. Is it better to send ping from client to server, or reverse?
5. Since `conn.ReadJSON()` will block, does that means I should use `conn.SetPingHandler()` to specify a handler, or just use the default handler?
   In either case, the ping need to be sent from client to server I guess.

---

### Sample ping from server (not sure is it proper)

I added a testing ping sent from fiber websocket server to js client, if needed:

```
        // ping
        // TODO: not sure is this needed ?
        // TODO: use goroutine pool ?
        if needPing {
            go func() {
                pingTicker := time.NewTicker(pingPeriod)
                defer func() {
                    pingTicker.Stop()
                }()
                time.Sleep(pingPeriod) // wait a while before start ping,
                for {
                    select {
                    case <-pingTicker.C:
                        conn.WriteControl(websocket.PingMessage, []byte("ping"), time.Now().Add(time.Second*5))
                        log.Debug("ping")
                    }
                }
            }()
        }
```

I also don't see any ping msg on client in chrome's devtools.

It's better to use `for{ select }` to handle both ping & normal msg I guess, but `conn.ReadJSON()` would block the goroutine, might need to create a channel for it? Didn't try yet.

BTW, any suggestion to the ping impl?

Comment: Also asked in fiber/websocket's github: https://github.com/gofiber/websocket/issues/117